# How to load a ContikiOS program to actual hardware (ESP8266 in my case)?

Tags: microcontroller, esp8266, contiki

I have tested my code on Contiki OS Cooja Simulator, I now want to transfer it to esp8266 module but could not find a proper any guide on how to transfer code from ContikiOS?

Answer (score 1):

It's not that simple - "transferring" the code to a microcontroller is the easy part! What you call "transfer" is more widely known as "programming", "flashing" or "uploading" in this area. Instruction how to do it with Contiki and Contiki-NG are in the tutorial here: https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/wiki/Tutorial:-Hello,-World!#running-the-example-on-a-real-device

However, for an embedded OS such as Contiki to work correctly on a specific microcontroller, not only must the microcontroller specified in compilation settings (so that the compilers knows what code to generate), the OS itself must be adapted to that specific microcontroller and the specific board. Each microcontroller has its own way of providing functionality that the OS needs, for example, hardware timers and interrupts. OS needs to *support* the microcontroller, that is, provide an adaptation layer between the OS core code and the API exposed by the hardware. Different boards may use the same microcontroller, but differ in the pins used for I/O, LEDs, peripherals available, and so on. Each of the supported boards must have a small adaptation layer in the OS as well.

Unfortunately ESP microcontrollers have never been officially supported by the Contiki OS, so you will need to get another hardware to try it out!